# Error mounting samba network drive (wrong fs type, bad option, ...)

Tags: networking, server, mount, samba, fstab

Yesterday I've installed ubuntu on a pc and want to use it as homeserver. I created some shares with samba and everythink worked perfect. But if i want to mount them to my system with this command: `sudo mount -a`, this error message comes:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on //192.168.178.71/Dateien,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
   need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
```

And this comes 3 times because i have 3 shares.

The `/etc/fstab` file:

```
#Mount Homeserver
//192.168.178.71/Dateien /home/hugeldugelking/Herold/ cifs credentials=/home/hugeldugelking/.credentials/smbcredentials,users,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
//192.168.178.71/minecraft_server /home/hugeldugelking/Spiele/Minecraft_Server/ cifs credentials=/home/hugeldugelking/.credentials/smbcredentials,users,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
//192.168.178.71/webserver /home/hugeldugelking/Programmierung/Webserver cifs credentials=/home/hugeldugelking/.credentials/smbcredentials,users,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

**PLEASE HELP**

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You don't have the helper program installed for either the nfs or cifs file system. For nfs based file system, following utility is required

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-common
```

To mount a Cifs file system, install the following utility

```
sudo apt install cifs-utils
```